# Calendar day color depending on list

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, calendar

I'm thinking about a calendar connected to the list of simple objects containing two properties: DateTime and string (containing hex color).

Is it possible to iterate from code level through day buttons or use some kind of data template in xaml to check if list contains specified date and return its color to the border?

Only thing I've found was Telerik solution but it requires their control libraries to work, I'd like to know if there are other options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used day to color multi value converter passing current day button and my colored days collection as values

```
public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var result = "Transparent";

        if (!(values[0] is DateTime))
            return result;

        ObservableCollection<Log> collection = null;

        if (values[1] is ObservableCollection<Log>)
            collection = (ObservableCollection<Log>) values[1];

        if (collection != null)
        {
            foreach (var log in collection.Where(log => (DateTime) values[0] == log.Date.Date))
            {
                result = log.BackgroundColor;
                break;
            }
        }

        return new SolidColorBrush((Color) ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(result));
    }

<Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
<Setter Property="BorderBrush">
    <Setter.Value>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource DayColorConv}" FallbackValue="Transparent">
            <Binding/>
            <Binding Path="CurrentLogs" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type panels:Schedule}}"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```